# Finding Orders With One Product And One OTHER Product From Another Category

Tags: mysql

Let's say I have a database where the relevant portions look like this:

```
PRODUCT TABLE

productid

categoryid

ORDER LINE ITEMS TABLE

orderid

productid
```

Let us also say that productid #1 is in category #1.

My goal is to find all orders that have BOTH a line item any product in categoryid #2 AND productid #1 (which is not in categoryid #2).  In other words, a list of all orderids where the customer's ordered both anything from categoryid #1001 AND product #1.

I'm sure there's an easy fix for this, but I'm blanking on it right now - all of my ANDs and ORs are getting tangled up, excluding one or the other!

Comment: Not sure if I follow your question. A little punctuation in your requirement might help. :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a table named `ORDER`:

```
select o.* --put actual column names here instead of *
from ORDER o
where o.orderid in (
 select orderid
 from PRODUCT p 
 inner join [ORDER LINE ITEMS] ol on p.productid = ol.productid
     and p.categoryid = 2
)
and o.orderid in (
 select orderid
 from [ORDER LINE ITEMS] ol
 where ol.productid = 1
)
```